# prevent immediate evaluation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm building a dynamic form in react.

I try to bind checked value of a radio button but the comparaison seems to be executed immediatelly.

How do I differ comparasion ?

```
buildRadio(field) {
    const radios = field.questionnairefieldlabelSet.map((label) => {
        const radioValue = `${field.id}-${label.id}`
        return <Form.Radio
                    key={radioValue}
                    label={label.text}
                    checked={this.state[field.id] === radioValue} // evaluated once, never changes on state change
                    value={radioValue}
                    onChange={(e, { value }) => {
                        this.setState({ [field.id]: value })}} />
    })

    return <Form.Group key={field.id}>
                {radios}                    
            </Form.Group>
}
```

I've tried to pass a function instead but I get an error message

```
checked={() => this.state[field.id] === radioValue}
```

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `checked` of type `function` supplied to `Checkbox`, expected `boolean`

Comment: why don't you try just: checked={this.state[field.id] === radioValue}

Comment: Your second try cannot work. The original code should work if the component is rerendered, which it should be on state change. What kind of component is `Form.Radio`?

Comment: @Ehssan because that's what causes the problem at first, () => this.state[field.id] === radioValue i smy second attempt

Comment: @Sulthan Form.Radio is a React Semantic UI component. https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form

Comment: @Yvain Can you show us where/how your state is changing? That expression _should_ be evaluated immediately, not deferred, but it should be evaluated _again_ when the component is re-rendered.

Comment: @JLRishe state is changed when clicking on radiobutton, handled by onchange method

Comment: Are you sure this is React Semantic UI and not React Form? If that's React Form, then the current value must be set on `Form.Group`. See https://github.com/react-tools/react-form/blob/master/src/components/form-fields/Radio.js#L34

Comment: @Sulthan Yes Form is from React Semantic UI, but I will try to set current value to group to see what happens